# basic html using jQuery to load top nav menu not inheriting styles

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm working on a strictly html web site for a non-profit group.  I'd like to make a single html file and load it in via ajax `.load()` so make future updates easier.  The `.load()` is working just fine but the drop down menus are not working, just the parent level is loading.  Now, if I take the page that is being loaded (copy and paste) it in place of the `div`, it works perfectly.

Here is the menu/page that is being loaded via ajax:

```
    <div class="navbar navbar_ clearfix">
    <div class="navbar-inner">
        <div class="nav-collapse nav-collapse_ collapse">
            <ul class="nav sf-menu clearfix">
                <li class="sub-menu"><a href="/adoptions.htm">Adopt</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="/adopt_a_cat.htm">Adopt a Cat</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/adopt_a_dog.htm">Adopt a Dog</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/vips.htm">VIPs</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="sub-menu"><a href="/donate_help.htm">Donate/Help</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="/make_a_donation.htm">Make A Donation</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/our_wish_list.htm">Our Wish List</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/volunteer.htm">Volunteer</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/virtual_foster.htm">Virtual Foster</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/be_a_voice.htm">Be A Voice</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the jquery ajax call (doesn't get any simpler than this):

```
$('#topNavBar').load('includes/_topNavBar.htm');
```

And here is the div tag the content is loaded into (if not hard coded):

```
<div id="topNavBar"></div>
```

I've really tired bouncing my head off of the keyboard; the html loaded via ajax should inherit the existing styling but it isn't.  I'm hoping the answer is here somewhere and I'm just missing it.

Comment: Make friends with the developer tools in your favorite browser. You'll spot the problem in no time. (Without a fiddle, there's not really anything more specific to say.)

Comment: Have you tried keeping the div hidden until the load finishes and puts the html content in it?

Comment: @StephenThomas - that's just it, everything looks the same either way.  Just really weird behavior.  I'll see if I can make a fiddle.

Comment: j-wells I need the content to be the same across all of the pages so that I only have to update one file instead of 20+.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot reproduce your problem. So my suggestions for you are to

1) make sure the AJAX load() occurs after your stylesheet and HTML elements are completely loaded:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
        <script src="jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
        <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="topNavBar"></div>

        <script type="text/javascript">    
            $('#topNavBar').load('_topNavBar.html');
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

or check for the $( document ).ready() event to wait until the page is loaded.

2) check if assigning the appropriate class on runtime in the developer console of your choice changes anything (e.g. $('#topNavBar>div').addClass("navbar") ). If this is not the case you might find your problem in your CSS e.g. a misspelled selector.

Comment: upon closer inspection, there is a class that is NOT being applied on mouseover the the nav menu so the drop down elements are not being applied.  I have the .load occurring in the doc ready and still not performing as expected.  (the styles are loading at the top of the doc and the .js are at the bottom).

Comment: Have you tried using the console as suggested by others? You can see the document's structure as it is loaded in the DOM. After the page has loaded, can you see all elements of your "_topNavBar.htm" as child elements of your "topNavBar" DIV? If yes, your problem has probably nothing to do with the AJAX call. Take a thorough look at your CSS, there might be a mismatch in naming or in the selectors you've used.

Comment: I'll take a look closer.  I suspect you are right in that it has nothing to do with the ajax call itself.  Thinks for pulling me out of this tunnel vision.  :)